# Linux (Ubuntu) Distribution to Development Build

Tags: linux-distributions, ubuntu-15.10

Why or why not would I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 15.10 or any Linux release to development build. What are the up and down sides of upgrading to 16.04. I have tried out a daily build in Boxes and I like some of the new features.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the epitome of an "Opinion oriented" question. I would generally say, if you want to spend your time administering an OS, then dailies are for you, but if you want to spend your time using a computer as a tool to support a task, they are not. if finding and reporting bugs is your bag, then by all means, the developer builds are for you. if you are contributing to the development of the distro, you would certianly want it. an app dev may want to make sure their stuff is compatible with an upcoming release. its all about what you want to use your box for.

Comment: I would like to do both. If that is what I want, should I dual boot the developement version with the stable release, or use a virtual machine?

Comment: a dual boot isn't a bad plan, but perhaps don't try it if the distro is upgrading the boot loader. VMs are wonderful, but it usually takes some time before the distro and the virtual hardware gel correctly. it may work marvelously, or you may have platform specific issues.

Comment: If you can do different partitions for the different system, so that you can have a full working computer in case you need...

Comment: I can do dual boot.